# Unable to run rinari-web-server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, rvm, rinari

When I run rinari-web-server I am getting this error:

```
/home/pedrorolo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /home/pedrorolo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/pedrorolo/workspace/geoptima-registrator/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/pedrorolo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/pedrorolo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/pedrorolo/workspace/geoptima-registrator/script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

I have the rvm emacs package installed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you used ruby - `rvm use 1.9.3`, also what is the command you run

Comment: How is your question related to emacs?

Comment: Rinari is an emacs mode for ruby on rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make this work by explicitly loading the rvm.el file in my .emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, fixed it by installing rvm.el

https://github.com/senny/rvm.el

Edit: duh, didn't fully read your question. Sorry.

Comment: Anyway your answer made me try to explicitly load rvm.el and than it worked.